# Navbar search wih materializecss and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, materialize

I'm new with materialize so I've been looking through the documentation, and a doubt came out.
To add a search box into the navbar, they use this example:

```
 <nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <form>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input id="search" type="search" required>
      <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My question is, usually when I use a form to make a search I put a `ng-click="search(param)"` in the submit button who in this case doesn't exist, so how should I make use of angular to do the search?.

Comment: What do mean by "do the search" ?

Comment: I meant to take the input and pass it to the function as I would do it with ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

You do it the exact same way. You just add a button to it.

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <form>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input id="search" type="search" required>
                <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="function()">
                Search
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a search using [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) in the input, so you'll call a event each time you input something

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <form>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="search" ng-model="searchString" ng-change="searchFor(searchString)">
        <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In your controller, declare the function `searchFor`

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', SearchController);

function SearchController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.searchFor = SearchFor;

  function SearchFor(searchString) {
    // Return if inputed less than 3 characteres
    if (searchString.length < 3)
      return;

    // else call your api to search for
    searchApi.get(searchString).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
  }
}
```